# Pandas Groupby using multiple criteria on different axis

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a `df` DataFrame like :

```
      | A | B | A_ | B_ |COMMON|
--------------------------------
0     | 1 | 3 | 0  | 1  | a    |
--------------------------------
1     | 8 | 5 | 4  | 0  | a    |
--------------------------------
2     | 3 | 6 | 2  | 4  | b    |
--------------------------------
3     | 9 | 9 | 1  | 7  | b    |
```

And I want to group all columns `X` with `X_` for all letters `A,B,...` (let's say, the group is called `X` as well), and group as well using `COMMON`. I would like to apply later function like `std()` to all the grouped values.

So the result would look like:

```
COMMON  |  A     |  B     |
---------------------------
a       |std(...)|std(...)|
---------------------------
b       |std(...)|std(...)|
```

I have been able to group either one or the other, using `df.groupby(['COMMMON'])` for one criteria and `.groupby(mapping_function, axis=1)` for the other one, but how do I use them together?

Another alternative for an intermediate step would be to concatenate individual columns so that I would get:

```
      | A | B |COMMON|
----------------------
0     | 1 | 3 |a    |
---------------------
1     | 8 | 5 |a    |
---------------------
2     | 3 | 6 |b    |
---------------------
3     | 9 | 9 |b    |
---------------------
0     | 0 | 1 |a    |
---------------------
1     | 4 | 0 |a    |
---------------------
2     | 2 | 4 |b    |
---------------------
3     | 1 | 7 |b    |
```

But I also don't know how to do that. 
Also as you might see, I don't really care about the index.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reshape first by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with removing `_` from column names (for better performance, because `strip` only few values) with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df = (df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('_'))
        .melt('COMMON')
        .pivot_table(index='COMMON',columns='variable', values='value', aggfunc='std'))

print (df)
variable         A         B
COMMON                      
a         3.593976  2.217356
b         3.593976  2.081666
```

Comment: Nice pivot :-) .

Answer (score 5):

IIUC

```
df.melt('COMMON').assign(variable=lambda x : x['variable'].str.rstrip('_')).\
       groupby(['COMMON','variable']).value.std().unstack()
Out[18]: 
variable         A         B
COMMON                      
a         3.593976  2.217356
b         3.593976  2.081666
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Just `groupby`

```
h = lambda x: x[-1][0]

df.set_index('COMMON', append=True).stack().groupby(['COMMON', h]).std().unstack()

               A         B
COMMON                    
a       3.593976  2.217356
b       3.593976  2.081666
```